# Reading json data and show it on web page

Tags: go

I'm studing web dev using golang as the back end. i have a API i need to fetch data from it.

what i did is i created a const to hold the URL as showing here:

```
const (
    locationsURL = "https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/locations"
)
```

then i created the struct:

```
type LocationData struct {
    Locations []string `json:"locations"`
}
```

then i created a function to fetch the data from URl

```
func fetchDataFromURL(url string, target interface{}) error {
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to fetch data, status code: %d", response.StatusCode)
    }

    // Read the response body
    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to read response body: %v", err)
    }

    // Print the response body for inspection
    //fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(responseBody))

    // Decode the response body into the target interface
    err = json.Unmarshal(responseBody, target)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to decode response body: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

after that a function to get location struct data:

```
func getLocationData() ([]LocationData, error) {
    var locations []LocationData
    err := fetchDataFromURL(locationsURL, &locations)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("Location data:", locations)

    return locations, nil
}
```

than i created home Handler function:

```
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    artists, err := getArtistData()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("Error fetching artist data from URL")
        return
    }

    locations, err := getLocationData()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("Error fetching location data from URL", err)
        return
    }

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("Error parsing template: ", err)
        return
    }

    data := struct {
        Artists   []Artist
        Locations []LocationData
    }{
        Artists:   artists,
        Locations: locations,
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("Error executing template: ", err)
        return
    }

    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.Error(w, "404: Page not found", http.StatusNotFound)
    }
}
```

when i run it i get this error

```
failed to decode response body: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.LocationData
```

i checked the json file data for locations it is the same this is a sample of the json file

```
"locations":["north_carolina-usa","georgia-usa","los_angeles-usa","saitama-japan","osaka-japan","nagoya-japan","penrose-new_zealand","dunedin-new_zealand"]
```

can any body please help me :)

Comment: The JSON at the end of your question is not valid. The error message does say you're trying to unmarshal an object into a slice variable, so I'd wager the actual data looks more like this: `{"locations": [...]}`, so unmarshal it into a single `LocationData` instance, rather than a slice of them. That's just an educated guess, because without seeing the full data (don't expect ppl to follow random links you post, include relevant info like that in the question), I can't say more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example program is unmarshaling into `[]LocationData`, where a single `LocationData` has `Locations []string`. The naming here makes it easy to misconfigure. :)

Here's a working example, parsing the minimum from the URL you provided:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Root struct {
    Index []Index `json:"index"`
}

type Index struct {
    Locations []string `json:"locations"`
}

func main() {
    var root Root
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(output), &root); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("entries: %d\n", len(root.Index))
}

const output = `{"index":[{"id":1,"locations":["north_carolina-usa","georgia-usa","los_angeles-usa","saitama-japan","osaka-japan","nagoya-japan","penrose-new_zealand","dunedin-new_zealand"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/1"},{"id":2,"locations":["playa_del_carmen-mexico","papeete-french_polynesia","noumea-new_caledonia"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/2"},{"id":3,"locations":["london-uk","lausanne-switzerland","lyon-france"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/3"},{"id":4,"locations":["victoria-australia","new_south_wales-australia","queensland-australia","auckland-new_zealand","yogyakarta-indonesia","bratislava-slovakia","budapest-hungary","minsk-belarus"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/4"},{"id":5,"locations":["california-usa","nevada-usa","georgia-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/5"},{"id":6,"locations":["california-usa","sao_paulo-brazil","san_isidro-argentina"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/6"},{"id":7,"locations":["california-usa","arizona-usa","texas-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/7"},{"id":8,"locations":["stockholm-sweden","werchter-belgium","lisbon-portugal","bilbao-spain","georgia-usa","bogota-colombia","sao_paulo-brazil"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/8"},{"id":9,"locations":["new_york-usa","dusseldorf-germany","aarhus-denmark","manchester-uk"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/9"},{"id":10,"locations":["frankfurt-germany","berlin-germany","stockholm-sweden","copenhagen-denmark","werchter-belgium"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/10"},{"id":11,"locations":["doha-qatar","minnesota-usa","illinois-usa","california-usa","mumbai-india"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/11"},{"id":12,"locations":["abu_dhabi-united_arab_emirates","new_york-usa","pennsylvania-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/12"},{"id":13,"locations":["westcliff_on_sea-uk","merkers-germany","illinois-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/13"},{"id":14,"locations":["nevada-usa","arizona-usa","california-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/14"},{"id":15,"locations":["london-uk","new_york-usa","maine-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/15"},{"id":16,"locations":["berlin-germany","copenhagen-denmark","aarhus-denmark","gothenburg-sweden"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/16"},{"id":17,"locations":["florida-usa","south_carolina-usa","north_carolina-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/17"},{"id":18,"locations":["pagney_derriere_barine-france","hamburg-germany","boulogne_billancourt-france","nimes-france","sion-switzerland","ostrava-czechia","klagenfurt-austria","freyming_merlebach-france"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/18"},{"id":19,"locations":["nevada-usa","london-uk","manchester-uk"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/19"},{"id":20,"locations":["zaragoza-spain","madrid-spain","barcelona-spain"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/20"},{"id":21,"locations":["rio_de_janeiro-brazil","recife-brazil"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/21"},{"id":22,"locations":["california-usa","leipzig-germany","salem-germany","monchengladbach-germany","cuxhaven-germany","skanderborg-denmark","amsterdam-netherlands","burriana-spain","oulu-finland","budapest-hungary","napoca-romania"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/22"},{"id":23,"locations":["riyadh-saudi_arabia","rio_de_janeiro-brazil","canton-usa","quebec-canada","new_york-usa","california-usa","las_vegas-usa","mexico_city-mexico","monterrey-mexico","del_mar-usa","berlin-germany","lisbon-portugal"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/23"},{"id":24,"locations":["washington-usa","west_melbourne-australia","amsterdam-netherlands","paris-france","manchester-uk","missouri-usa","chicago-usa","birmingham-uk","copenhagen-denmark"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/24"},{"id":25,"locations":["west_melbourne-australia","sydney-australia","madison-usa","toronto-canada","cleveland-usa","new_york-usa","boston-usa","texas-usa","utah-usa","california-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/25"},{"id":26,"locations":["manchester-uk","glasgow-uk","dublin-ireland","cardiff-uk","london-uk","aberdeen-uk","stockholm-sweden","madrid-spain","paris-france","warsaw-poland","berlin-germany","milan-italy"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/26"},{"id":27,"locations":["michigan-usa","new_hampshire-usa","new_york-usa","warsaw-poland","sochaux-france","lyon-france","eindhoven-netherlands","oslo-norway","amsterdam-netherlands","colorado-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/27"},{"id":28,"locations":["jakarta-indonesia","huizhou-china","texas-usa","michigan-usa","changzhou-china","hong_kong-china","colorado-usa","sanya-china","aalborg-denmark","washington-usa","new_york-usa","toronto-canada","seattle-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/28"},{"id":29,"locations":["omaha-usa","kansas_city-usa","st_louis-usa","indianapolis-usa","rosemont-usa","grand_rapids-usa","toronto-usa","montreal-usa","newark-usa","uniondale-usa","philadelphia-usa","hershey-usa","pittsburgh-usa","washington-usa","columbia-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/29"},{"id":30,"locations":["santiago-chile","sao_paulo-brazil","los_angeles-usa","houston-usa","atlanta-usa","new_orleans-usa","philadelphia-usa","london-uk","frauenfeld-switzerland","turku-finland"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/30"},{"id":31,"locations":["las_vegas-usa","brooklyn-usa","boston-usa","washington-usa","philadelphia-usa","montreal-canada","toronto-usa","new_york-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/31"},{"id":32,"locations":["frankfurt-germany","berlin-germany","stockholm-sweden","copenhagen-denmark","imola-italy","vienna-austria","london-uk","krakow-poland","budapest-hungary","zurich-switzerland"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/32"},{"id":33,"locations":["philadelphia-usa","paris-france","amityville-usa","chicago-usa","minneapolis-usa","detroit-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/33"},{"id":34,"locations":["oakland-usa","charlotte-usa","los_angeles-usa","berlin-germany","houston-usa","chicago-usa","inglewood-usa","madrid-spain"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/34"},{"id":35,"locations":["windsor-canada","brooklyn-usa","birmingham-uk","cincinnati-usa","anaheim-usa","chicago-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/35"},{"id":36,"locations":["manila-philippines","mumbai-india","auckland-new_zealand","brisbane-australia","melbourne-australia","sydney-australia"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/36"},{"id":37,"locations":["bogota-colombia","rio_de_janeiro-brazil","sao_paulo-brazil","santiago-chile","san_isidro-argentina","lima-peru"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/37"},{"id":38,"locations":["paris-france","groningen-netherlands","antwerp-belgium","vienna-austria","glasgow-uk","london-uk"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/38"},{"id":39,"locations":["mexico_city-mexico","pico_rivera-usa","chicago-usa","boston-usa","philadelphia-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/39"},{"id":40,"locations":["london-uk","berwyn-usa","georgia-usa","new_york-usa","dallas-usa","houston-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/40"},{"id":41,"locations":["california-usa","birmingham-uk","brixton-uk","london-uk","rotselaar-belgium"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/41"},{"id":42,"locations":["california-usa","rio_de_janeiro-brazil","los_angeles-usa","alabama-usa","massachusetts-usa","athens-greece","florence-italy","landgraaf-netherlands"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/42"},{"id":43,"locations":["sydney-australia","melbourne-australia","burswood-australia","wellington-new_zealand","abu_dhabi-united_arab_emirates"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/43"},{"id":44,"locations":["madrid-spain","seville-spain","los_angeles-usa","bangkok-thailand","manila-philippines","taipei-taiwan","hong_kong-china","seoul-south_korea"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/44"},{"id":45,"locations":["munich-germany","mannheim-germany","san_francisco-usa","santiago-chile","buenos_aires-argentina","porto_alegre-brazil","sao_paulo-brazil","belo_horizonte-brazil"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/45"},{"id":46,"locations":["california-usa","sao_paulo-brazil","porto_alegre-brazil","la_plata-argentina","london-uk"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/46"},{"id":47,"locations":["dubai-united_arab_emirates","willemstad-netherlands_antilles","florida-usa","florida-usa","mexico_city-mexico","santiago-chile","sao_paulo-brazil","brasilia-brazil"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/47"},{"id":48,"locations":["texas-usa","oklahoma-usa","california-usa","illinois-usa","scheessel-germany","st_gallen-switzerland","gdynia-poland","arras-france"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/48"},{"id":49,"locations":["washington-usa","california-usa","california-usa","arizona-usa","florida-usa"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/49"},{"id":50,"locations":["mexico_city-mexico","sao_paulo-brazil","buenos_aires-argentina","santiago-chile","lima-peru"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/50"},{"id":51,"locations":["bogota-colombia","san_jose-costa_rica","nevada-usa","massachusetts-usa","massachusetts-usa","nickelsdorf-austria","milan-italy","lisbon-portugal"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/51"},{"id":52,"locations":["oregon-usa","vancouver-canada","nevada-usa","colorado-usa","munich-germany","prague-czechia","milan-italy"],"dates":"https://groupietrackers.herokuapp.com/api/dates/52"}]}`

// output: entries: 52
```